# How can i select items with negative scale value in python to Blender?

Tags: python

How can i select items with negative scale value in python to Blender? Additionally script should only check items with sufix _kill in their name but that i can do with chatgpt :P

Thank You!

Comment: What do you mean by `select items`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will only select mesh objects with a negative scale.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


for object in context.visible_objects:
    if object.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    
    if object.scale.x < 0 or object.scale.y < 0 or object.scale.z < 0:
        object.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Since vectors are sequences, you can also do `if min(object.scale) < 0:`